# angularjs update button text based $http responses ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update button value on-click based $http responses. I want to change button value to **Processing...** while making $http request with ng-click function. And based on Success/Error response, need to update text **Success** and **Try Again** etc.

I'm using **ui-router** and I've different form elements distributed in different states, e.g. Email, User, Password etc.

**In my View, I've following code in Email State.**

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterEmailController">
  <div class="form-group" style="position: relative;" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.useremail.$dirty && form.useremail.$error.required && form.useremail.$invalid }">
    <input type="email" name="useremail" id="useremail" ng-model="RegisterEmailController.userDetail.useremail" ng-required="true">
    <span ng-show="form.useremail.$dirty && form.useremail.$error.required" class="help-block text-sm text-danger pl-4">Oops! Incorrect email address, or field is empty</span>
    <span ng-hide="form.useremail.$dirty && form.useremail.$error.required" class="help-block d-block text-sm text-danger px-4">{{ErrorMsg}}</span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="RegisterEmailController.nexStep()">{{buttonTxt}}</button>
</div>
```

**In my Controller**

```
var controller = this;
$scope.buttonTxt = 'Next Step';

controller.nexStep = function() {
  $scope.buttonTxt = 'Processing...';
  if ( validation_conditions ) {
    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: ApiURL,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      data: getData
    }).then(function success(response) {
      $scope.buttonTxt = 'Success';
    }, function error(response) {
      $scope.buttonTxt = 'Try Again';
      return;
    });
  } else {
    $scope.buttonTxt = 'Try Again';
    return;
  }
}
```

With above code i can't be able to change button text on click, i tried with `controller.buttonTxt` as well but it doesn't print value at all on init. I also tried **ng-bind** directive but no luck.

Please assist me where I'm doing wrong. As far as i can estimate that `$scope` might conflicting with `this` (var controller = this;) in controller.

Also how can i add success/error class to input parent element based on response?

Thanks for reading my query and i appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You need to assign a controller alias  in `ng-controller` when not using $scope

Comment: Can u make a plunkr with the code?

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, by assinging controller alias my problem is resolved, though have to fix couple of more things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var controller = function ($http) {
  var validation_conditions
  var ApiURL = 'google.com'
  var getData = ''
  this.buttonTxt = 'Next Step';
  
  this.nexStep = function() {
    this.buttonTxt = 'Processing...';
    if ( validation_conditions ) {
      $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: ApiURL,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        data: getData
      }).then(function success(response) {
        this.buttonTxt = 'Success';
      }, function error(response) {
        this.buttonTxt = 'Try Again';
        return;
      });
    } else {
      this.buttonTxt = 'Try Again';
      return;
    }
  }
}
controller.$inject = ['$http']

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('RegisterEmailController',controller);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="RegisterEmailController as ctrl">
  <div class="form-group" style="position: relative;" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.useremail.$dirty && form.useremail.$error.required && form.useremail.$invalid }">
    <input type="email" name="useremail" id="useremail" ng-model="RegisterEmailController.userDetail.useremail" ng-required="true">
    <span ng-show="form.useremail.$dirty && form.useremail.$error.required" class="help-block text-sm text-danger pl-4">Oops! Incorrect email address, or field is empty</span>
    <span ng-hide="form.useremail.$dirty && form.useremail.$error.required" class="help-block d-block text-sm text-danger px-4">{{ctrl.ErrorMsg}}</span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.nexStep()">{{ctrl.buttonTxt}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ppollono, my issue is resolved. Further can you please assist how can i add valid/error class to input based on success/error responses?

Comment: To be able to help you with this you need an endpoint to get the responses (success/error)

Comment: yes you're right, i was able to add conditional classes with the response i get. Thanks for following up (thumbs-up)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterEmailController as $registerEmail">
```

and then in button:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="RegisterEmailController.nexStep()">{{$registerEmail.buttonTxt}}</button>
```